# create lists of lists by grouping values in a list based on values in another list using python

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, grouping, sublist

I have list which has some values

```
A=[3,4,5]
```

I have another list which has some values as shown below

```
B=[11,20,30,40,51,89,50,36,29,90,48,94,45,67,34]
```

I want to create a new list named as C which would contain sublists, where each sublist will be created according to the values present in list A. Values in list A will act as an end index for each sublist.

```
c=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    print A[i]
    for x in range(0,len(B),A[i]):
        c.append(B[x:x+A[i]])
```

but my problem is it only takes last values of list A and groups according to it. How can I make sure that all the values in list A are taken in order to create a list c with sub lists?

it generates an output like this

```
[[11, 20, 30, 40, 51], [89, 50, 36, 29, 90], [48, 94, 45, 67, 34]]
```

but I need

```
[[11, 20, 30, 40], [51], [89]]
```

I want to achieve this.I want to group sub lists based on the values present in the list A, so 0 will be the starting index and three will be the ending index for the first sublist which would be [11,20,30,40] and for second sublist 3 would be the starting index and 4 would be the ending index, so second sublist would be [51], for third sublist the starting index would be 4 and ending index would be 5 so third sublist would be [89].Hence finally my list should look like this

```
C=[[11,20,30,40],[51],[89]]
```

Comment: I indented your second for loop to actually take advantage of `i`. My output does not match yours: `[[11, 20, 30], [40, 51, 89], [50, 36, 29], [90, 48, 94], [45, 67, 34]...]`

Comment: I f I understood you correctly, as per your requirement, shouldn't be desired list be the group of 3,4,5 elements instead of 4,5,6 elements?

Comment: A=[3,4,5] this list represents end indexes , we should be using this to frame sub lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following approach:

```
A = [3,4,5]
B = [11,20,30,40,51,89,50,36,29,90,48,94,45,67,34]

C = []
for k,v in enumerate(A):
    C.append(B[k:v+1] if k == 0 else B[A[k-1]+1:v+1])

print(C)
```

The output:

```
[[11, 20, 30, 40], [51], [89]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!This is what I am looking for. What if my list B is [11,20,30,40,"end",51,"end",89,"end",50,36,29,90,48,94,45,67,34]. I want to delete those end strings but still should get the same output??

Comment: @user1681102, filtering out "end" strings `B = [v for v in B if isinstance(v, int)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
A=[3,4,5]


B=[11,20,30,40,51,89,50,36,29,90,48,94,45,67,34]


new_list = [B[:a+1] if i == 0 else [B[a]] for i, a in enumerate(A)]
```

Comment: Kindly ignore my above question. I want to achieve this.I want to group sub lists based on the values present in the list A, so 0 will be the starting index and three will be the ending index for the first sublist which would be [11,20,30,40] and for second sublist 3 would be the starting index and 4 would be the ending index, so second sublist would be [51], for third sublist the starting index would be 4 and ending index would be 5 so third sublist would be [89].Hence finally my list should look like this C=[[11,20,30,40],[51],[89]]